# Select внутри цикла foreach

Tags: php

Есть цикл `foreach`, который отвечает за вывод `<option>` внутри `<select>`. Мне нужно разместить  `$term->term_id` в атрибуты `<select>`-а, но сам тег `<select>` находятся вне цикла `foreach ( $terms as $term )` и не работают. Если помещаю `<select>` внутрь `foreach`, то естественно ломается структура `html`. Есть ли варианты решения данной проблемы?

```
  <?php if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'services' )) ) :
    echo '<select id="ingredients-' . $term->term_id . '" value="' . $term->term_id . '" name="ingredientfilter[]"><option>Select</option>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
        echo '<option id="ingredients-' . $term->term_id . '" value="' . $term->term_id . '" name="ingredientfilter[]">' . $term->name . '</option>'; 
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';
   endif; ?>
```

Comment: зачем тебе `$term->term_id`  в `select`, если это отвечает за каждый ingridients?  В чём смысл?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пытаюсь переделать из checkbox в select из этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407952/ajax-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80-wordpress-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно буферизировать результат работы цикла в строку и потом вставить необходимое значение. Остается вопрос, в цикле вероятнее всего будет множество term_id, какой вам конкретно нужен? Еще в вашем коде ошибка, в теге [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) не должно быть атрибута `value`, выбранное значение задается атрибутом `selected` в теге `option`

```
<?php if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'services' )) ) :
ob_start();
echo '<select id="#ID#" name="ingredientfilter[]"><option>Select</option>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    $termId = $term->term_id;
    echo '<option',
        ' id="ingredients-', $term->term_id, '"',
        ' value="', $term->term_id, '"',
        ' name="ingredientfilter[]">',
        $term->name,
        '</option>'; 
endforeach;
echo '</select>';
$strHtml = ob_get_clean();
echo str_replace('#ID#',$termId,$strHtml);
endif; ?>
```

И не используйте конкатенацию в `echo` она работает дольше, чем просто вывод через запятую

Comment: Мне нужно передавать данные в select для фильтра (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407952/ajax-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80-wordpress-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8) по этому в select должны быть value="', $term->term_id, '" и id="ingredients-', $term->term_id, '", иначе фильтр не работает.

Comment: В таком случае id будет не уникальный, т.к. будет существовать option с таким же id, а это ошибка, про атрибут value я уже написал. Думаю, здесь проблема не в селекте, а в самом фильтре